# Error trying to copy/paste large file through remote connection

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, remote-access, copy-paste, remote-desktop

I am trying to copy a large file (about 4gb) from my local PC and paste it on a cloud PC through a remote connection. I get an unpecified error whenever I try to copy paste it the normal way, and according to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/2258090) the problem is because only files smaller than 2gb are supported.

I am trying to use the alternative method 2 in that link to get the file through, but I am getting an error in the console.

It says to use

```
xcopy \\tsclient\c\myfiles\LargeFile d:\temp
```

So I put

```
xcopy \\tsclient\C:\R2 2012 Microsoft Server ISO\ServerR2 2012 d:\temp
```

"C:\R2 2012 Microsoft Server ISO\ServerR2 2012" being the path of my file on my local machine.

But I get the error

```
Invalid number of parameters
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, does anyone have experience using this command for file copying?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try putting quotes around paths that have spaces in the command

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried using this xcopy \\tsclient\"C:\R2 2012 Microsoft Server ISO\ServerR2 2012" d:\temp. Not sure if those quotes are at the appropriate place. Instead of the "Invalid number of parameters" error I now  how "Invalid drive specification, 0 File(s) copied" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldnt find a way to get the copy/paste to work with the large files, instead I used a BitTorrent Sync(similar to drop box) to upload the files to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think sharing the drive from your PC to the PC you're connecting to is more suitable in the given context. Check this article: https://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/18/remote-desktop-file-copy.aspx/

Basically, do this:

- When the Remote Desktop window appears, click on the Options button
- Then choose the Local Resources tab
- Click More
- Choose the disk you want to share
- Now, you are able to see your drive in the file explorer of the remote PC